# how to store response from http.post and set state

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm using http.post node.js to post to https://api.mmitnetwork.com/Token to get an access Token.

How do I take the reponse I get back and set the state?

```
var App = React.createClass ({
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      token: ''
    }
  },
  componentDidMount() {
    var _this = this;
    var request = http.post('https://api.mmitnetwork.com/Token', {grant_type: 'password', username: 'myusername', password: 'mypassword'}, function(response) {
console.log(response.statusCode);
  response.on('data', function(chunk) {
    console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);

    _this.setState({
      token: response.chunk.access_token
    })
  });
})
request.on('error', function(err) {
  console.error(err.message);
})
},
render() {
  {this.state.token}
}
```

Comment: Can you tell what isn't working you your current implementation? Your render method is clearly wrong, you have to return a valid jsx expression. ie: `return (<p>{this.state.toke}</p>)`

Comment: It is logging the response back with my access token but it isn't setting the state of token to it

Comment: How do you know? as I mention before your render method is wrong. Also you're printing `chunk` and using `response.chunk` to set the state

Comment: I figured it out. thanks